# Good examples of non-game Marmalade apps?

Tags: android, c++, ios, marmalade

Does anyone have any good examples of iOS or Android apps made with the Marmalade platform, that are **not games**?

We know plenty of great games have been developed with Marmalade, but we're struggling to see a good list of examples of non-games, particularly any employing native interface elements across both iOS and Android.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know when people ask that question there is answer "NO" or no response.

Marmalade forum:
https://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/forum/will-marmalade-be-serious-platform-business-and-general-purpose-applications

No one from Marmalade team even responded. Only licensees.

Answer (score 7):

This is one I developed:

iOS
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nordic-naturals/id554262658?ls=1&mt=8

Android:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordicnaturals.app&hl=en

Marmalades support for Native UI is somewhat limited which posed some difficulties and the performance was also poor when using the Native UI functions which also limited what I could do.

Answer (score 1):

I also havn't seen any non-game app made by marmalade, although their support for Phonegap api shows that marmalade guys are seriously trying to change it. In my view Marmalade is pretty stable to use(I have used it's C++ version only) for even a non-game app too.

Whatever functionality it lacks can be easily developed using EDK and added back to marmalade project.

Comment: PhoneGap on Marmalade is too young. I used PhoneGap 1.8 for iOS. Instead of Marmalade's version 1.4

Comment: Yeah, but atleast they are trying, may be in next version or so they'll upgrade the api version. Till then we just need to wait.